# How to make logo responsive in react bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrp and I am trying to change the width of the logo depending on the screen size. What is the best way to achieve this? This is my code:

```
<Navbar.Brand href="#home">
        <img
          src={logo}
          width={270}
          className="d-inline-block align-top"
          alt="Overland NInja Logo"
        />
</Navbar.Brand>
```

I would like the width to be 190 on mobile screens.

Comment: You could use CSS media queries to change the width of the image at a certain screen size

Comment: doesn't work. Do you have a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of using CSS Media Queries to resize elements (best seen in full screen mode)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #logo {
    width: 190px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/kXciY0r.jpeg" width="270px"/>
```

You can utilize this for a CSS solution to change the image based on the screen size.